# PHP datetime format and string

Tags: php, javascript, date, datetime, strtotime

I'm building a Joomla component for online exams and I'm struggling with format conversions.
Basically I want to get a difference between to dates (in seconds) and then convert them to minutes but no matter what I try and what I search online (including SO) I can't seem to get things working properly.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$sessionStuff = $session->get('quizSession');

$time_config =& JFactory::getConfig();
$time_jnow =& JFactory::getDate();
$time_jnow->setOffset( $time_config->getValue('config.offset' ));
$time_now = strtotime($time_jnow);
$started_time = strtotime($sessionStuff['lineSession']['started_on']);

$elapsedtime = /*gmdate("H:i:s",*/ abs($started_time - $time_now)/*)*/;
echo "Start_time: " . $started_time . '- Type: ' . gettype($started_time). '<br/>';
echo "Now: " . $time_now . '- Type: ' . gettype($time_now). '<br/>';
echo "Elapsed time: " . $elapsedtime . /*'- Type: ' . gettype($elapsedtime) .*/ '<br/>';

$availabletime = $started_time - $elapsedtime;

if(empty($sessionStuff)){
    $availabletime = ($this->quiz->time_limit) ? $this->quiz->time_limit : 0;
} else {
    $availabletime = $started_time - $elapsedtime;
}

echo "Available: " . $availabletime . '- Type: ' . gettype($availabletime);
?>
```

Which outputs the following:

> Start_time: 1365756958- Type: integer
>
> Now: 1365757510- Type: integer
>
> Elapsed time: 552
>
> Available: 1365756406- Type: integer

Then I have this JS code which receives a value (in minutes) and converts it to the correct format:

```
    var hours ;
    var minutes ; 
    var seconds ;
    var t ;
    var availableTime ;
    var remainingTime ;

window.onload = function () {

    listener();

    availableTime = <?php
                        echo ($this->quiz->time_limit) ? $this->quiz->time_limit : 0;;                       
                    ?> ;
    if (availableTime)
    {
        hours = Math.floor(availableTime / 60) ;
        minutes = availableTime % 60;

        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = '0' + hours ;
        }

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes ;
        }

        seconds = '00' ;

        var timer = document.getElementById('timer') ;
        timer.innerHTML = '<?php echo JText::_('TIME_REMAINING') ; ?> ' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds ;

        remainingTime = availableTime *= 60 ;

        updateTimer();
    }
}

function pad(number, length) 
{
    var str = '' + number;
    if (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }

    return str;
}

function updateTimer()
{
    seconds -= 1 ;
    seconds = pad(seconds, 2) ;

    if (seconds < 0)
    {
        seconds = '59' ;
        minutes -= 1 ;
        minutes = pad(minutes, 2) ;

        if (minutes < 0)
        {
            minutes = '59' ;
            hours -= 1 ;
            hours = pad(hours, 2) ;

            if (hours < 0)
            {
                hours = minutes = seconds = '00' ;
                document.getElementById('timeUp').value = 1 ;
                document.jquarks_quiz.submit();
                return true ;
            }
        }
    }

    var timer = document.getElementById('timer') ;
    timer.innerHTML = '<?php echo JText::_('TIME_REMAINING') ; ?> ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds ;

    remainingTime -= 1 ;
    if (Math.floor(availableTime / 10) == remainingTime ) 
    {
        timer.style.color="white" ;
        timer.style.backgroundColor = "#DD0000" ;
    }

    t = setTimeout("updateTimer()", 1000);
}
```

If I use the "native" formats (in PHP) for this piece of code:

```
$time_now = $time_jnow;
$started_time = $sessionStuff['lineSession']['started_on'];
```

I get the ouput:

> Start_time: 2013-04-12 09:55:58- Type: string
>
> Now: 2013-04-12 10:23:20- Type: object

Now, What I intend is to calculate the time difference between 'started_time' and 'time_now' and (if it's a page refresh and the session is set) subtract the 'elapsedtime' to the 'started_time' so that the timeout counter will continue from where it left off.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get things working correctly. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've already lost way too much time with this and PHP is not my *forte*.
How can I achieve the intended goal?

#### EDIT:

I realize that JS 'availableTime' is getting a constant time, but that is just for debugging purposes for now. Once everything is working fine it will be fed with the PHP '$availabletime' output.

#### EDIT 2:

I seem to not have been explicit in what the objective is.
Once an exam starts, let's say there are 15 minutes available. Assuming that after 1min and 31sec (00:01:31) the user refreshes the page, the available time should be 13minutes and 29 seconds (00:13:29).
This is the behaviour I'm not being able to achieve although I *can* perform the calculations for how much time (in seconds) has passed.

Comment: So when you change something in the script you get a different output ... I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Of course that when I change the script I get a different output :P but the problem is, what is the correct way to calculate the time difference (already done) do the calculations (subtract the elapsedtime to the startedtime) to retrieve the correct available time, and convert it to minutes so JS can then perform the right calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really simple way to do it.

```
 // Define your time strings
 $date1 = new DateTime("2013-01-01 07:00:00");
 $date2 = new DateTime("2014-01-01 03:17:00");

 // Perform a bit of black hoodoo magic
 $interval = $date1->diff($date2,true);

 // Output the result in a formatted fashion
 echo $interval->format("%d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
 // Or as a number of seconds. This is a bit more complicated.
 echo (($interval->y * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($interval->m * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($interval->d * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($interval->h * 60 * 60) + 
           ($interval->i * 60) + 
           $interval->s); 
 // For more info, check this out along with the doc:
 var_dump($interval);
```

This allows you to abstract away all the calculations you are doing in order to focus on the logic. What is going wrong?

Comment: I believe the problem is related to having "started_time" as a String (retrieved from the Session variable) and the $time_now as a date. Upon that I get lost in how to do the right conversions and calculations (although $elapsedtime is retrieving the intended value, I just can't find a way to subtract it from the $started_time  and retrieve the correct value, which is basically the time left until "expiration")

Comment: `DateTime` can take just about any form of timestamp you can throw at it. This is why I mentioned it and gave you an example - it saves you from having to do all the maths (that, and it also deals with DST all by itself). So, assuming you have an $time_now DateTime object and $started_time DateTime object, all you need to do is ->diff them absolutely to get the result.

Comment: Well, I had already tried that road unsuccessfully since $started_time is a string and I can't seem to get it to convert to the correct format

Comment: Have you even tried the code I suggested? `2013-04-12 09:55:58` is perfectly understood by the `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: I did. I don't know if it has something to do with Joomla, but the page fails to load upon that.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tested once again and it's ouputting fine now. I probably had an error which I didn't notice. BTW, running 5.4.4

Comment: Does your code work now? And yes, I asked for the version because `DateTime` was completely merged to PHP trunk in PHP 5.2